# How can I sum value across entries assigned to a category for a given year across multiple years?

Tags: templating

I have a category group named `country`.   Each entry in `posts` is assigned to a `country` and a `dollar value`.  `dollar value` is a field, NOT a table cell.

On a country's given page (i.e., a category page), I want to sum the total value across all entries assigned to a given country by year (date posted) across all years for which there are entries.

Help...

Answer (score 1):

```
{% amount = craft.entries
   .postDate(['and', '>=' someDate, '<=' ~ someOtherTime])
   .select('dollar')
   .relatedTo(category)
   .sum()
%}
```

Loop through all years and sum the value